# How do I request a cookie when server rendering on hapi?

Tags: cookies, fetch, server-side, hapi.js

I know that when using express, a cookie can be requested with the following code:

```
req.get('cookie')
```

However, I am now facing an issue when requesting a cookie using a hapi server.

The code for requesting a cookie should be the following:

```
request.state['COOKIE_NAME']
```

However, my `request.state` is always emtpy when server rendering my pages. When the cookie is request on the client, there is no issue, the `request.state` is populated with the cookies.

On my server file, I am using the `onPreResponse` hook as follows:

```
server.ext( 'onPreResponse', ( request, reply ) => {
...
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/getcookie', {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {'Cookie': request.state['COOKIE_NAME']} // Still empty
  })
...
});
```

The hapi Route is:

```
{
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/getcookie',
  config: {
    auth: false
},
  handler: ( request, reply ) => {
    console.log('GET COOKIE ROUTE: ', request.state); // <-- this is empty when server rendering

    reply({
      statusCode: 200,
      message: 'get cookie',
      data: {
        text: request.state
      }
    })
    .code(200);
}
```

The cookies are being set without a problem and I can retrieve them on the client as well. The issue is when I try to get the cookie on the server.

If you need any more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was a bit hard to understand for me. You write...

> The cookies are being set without a problem and I can retrieve them on the client as well. The issue is when I try to get the cookie on the server.

... but I do not see any code that actually sets a cookie value. So I cannot understand how you would successfully get in on the client. And to request the same route in the servers `onPreResponse` extension point with some `fetch` method is also not clear to me.

I wrote a small and complete example which actually sets a cookie and also makes use of the `onPreResponse` extension point.

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Path = require('path');

// Create a server with a host and port
const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
  port: 3000
});

//Define the cookie
server.state('data', {
    encoding: 'base64json'
});

// Add the route
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/getcookie',
  handler: function(request, reply) {

    const counterState = request.state.data.counter;
    const counter = counterState ? counterState + 1 : 1;

    return reply({
      statusCode: 200,
      message: 'get cookie',
      currentState: request.state
    })
    .state('data', {counter: counter}); //<-- You missed to actually SET your cookie!
  }
});

server.ext( 'onPreResponse', ( request, reply ) => {

  //Here you have full access to the original request
  console.log("PreResponse counter value: " + request.state.data.counter);

  return reply.continue();

});

// Start the server
server.start((err) => {

  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

I hope this helps you understand how to work with cookies in hapi and somehow presents a solution to your specific problem.